# ExtJs, get a element in the extended class

Tags: javascript, extjs5, getelementsbyname

I have done some research on google, but I could find answer to this

I have a view X and it extend another view Y so I want to get element under the view Y, notice that there is also the same element under the view X with the same name.

When I try this.down('[name=nameOfElement]') under the X view, I get the X element. but I want to get the Y element

Comment: your explanation is way to abstract to answer that question. please add an example... and when you extend a class, this should be one and the same element, not two elements. you might be referring to the wrong one instance of the class.

Comment: Instead of getting element by this.down try getting the required element by reference, i.e this.getElementByReference check documentation, give the views meaningful reference variables